# Google App Engine - DELETE JPQL Query and Cascading

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jpql

I noticed that the children of PersistentUser are not deleted when using the JPQL query below. However, the children are deleted if I perform an `entityManager.remove(object)`. Is this expected? Why doesn't the JPQL query below also perform a cascaded delete?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "persistentUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<PersistentLogin> persistentLogins;

...

@Override
@Transactional
public final void removeUserTokens(final String username) {
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "DELETE FROM PersistentUser p WHERE username = :username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected, the JPQL delete operation does not cascade. From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations
>
> (...)
>
> A delete operation only applies to
>   entities of the specified class and
>   its subclasses. **It does not cascade
>   to related entities**.