# Correct approach to using JPA 2

Tags: jpa, jpql

I saw [this link at Nabble](http://old.nabble.com/JPA%3a-Cascade.REMOVE-not-working-for-unidirectional-OneToMany-Relationship-td18574083.html) where someone (James Sutherland) stated to someone that they were "executing a delete all JPQL query. This is basically similar to executing your own SQL, you are responsible for executing the query correctly to maintain your constraints.

This is not the normal way to delete objects in JPA.  In JPA you normally read the object, then call remove() on it.".

I was wondering if this is true or not; based on how difficult it's been to remove more than simple tables, I'd start thinking this is correct.

My thoughts thus far are to do it like this:

1. Perform select statements, however particular they may be (e.g.
   select all students where student courses > 4 and marks >= 60 and
   student registration between 2011 and 2012).
2. Display/edit/delete 
   objects (so EntityManager merge/persist/remove)
3. Rinse, lather, and so on

Does this sound reasonable as an approach to how one is suppose to use the JPA or am I off base?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of JPA. You load objects, and modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cascading of remove was discussed here: [Google App Engine - DELETE JPQL Query and Cascading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995693). Also for instance doing batch updates won't update version column when optimistic locking is used. Thus batch updates/deletes are a bit crippled in JPA.

But I wouldn't say *This is not the normal way to delete objects in JPA*. When I need to delete 2, 20 or 200 objects based on some condition selecting and fetching them first just to call `remove()` on each is a bad idea most of the time.

After all batch updates/deletes are there in the specification for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I guess one must go back to using a structured query language then after all for doing deletes/updates? To me this seems to almost defeat the purpose of an ORM framework.

Comment: @CodesNChaos: I never said that! SQL has all the disadvantages of bulk updates/deletes in JPA QL without adding much benefit (maybe it is *slightly* faster). What I am saying is that bulk updates not always behave exaclty according to the semantics of pure object-oriented JPA approach. But neither SQL does. PS: 17 minutes is not a fast response on SO ;-).

Comment: The reason why I question the use of a query language (be it SQL or JPQL) is that it requires the programmer to delve back into, well, the query language and thus keep track of cascading and foreign key constraints.

That said, I see your point on bulk deletes, 1,000,000 records sent for the purpose of a delete would be silly. :)